# Helmholtz equation and sources

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

it is known that starting from the Maxwell equations it is possible to get the following Helmholtz equations:

[image]

In time domain it corresponds to a sinusoidal EM field, according to the wave equation:

[image]

Now my question is: is the time - behaviour of E/H always sinusoidal? It seems quite strange to me: I did not see any assumption of sinusoidal behaviour of current/charge sources. From this result it seems to me that sources can have any time - behaviour (also constant) and there will be a sine EM wave in time. I think I have missed some part of the reasoning.

Comment: You missed the part where the source is assumed to be sinusoidal. This can be as a direct ansatz, or as a Fourier decomposition of the general solution. The details will depend on where you actually saw this material.

Comment: The wave equation does not only have sinusoidal solutions.

Comment: Where did $k^{2}$ in the first equation come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Fourier's Theorem, there are a very broad class of functions that can be approximated to arbitrary accuracy by sums of sinusoidal functions. This means that if you can solve the Helmholtz equation for a sinusoidal source, you can also solve it for any source whose behavior can be described by a Fourier series. In fact, since the Helmholtz wave equation is a linear PDE, you can solve it for almost any arbitrary source $f(r)$ by:

1. Decomposing $f(r)$ into sinusoidal components,
2. Solving the Helmholtz wave equation for each component, and
3. Adding the solutions back together.